# JMS Serializer Annotation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using Doctrine2 and [JMS Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer), but the serializer is throwing a weird error:

> AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The class "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\PrePersist" is not annotated with @Annotation. Are you sure this class can be used as annotation? If so, then you need to add @Annotation to the *class* doc comment of "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\PrePersist". If it is indeed no annotation, then you need to add @IgnoreAnnotation("ORM\PrePersist") to the *class* doc comment of method User\User::prePersist().

That happens when I try to serialize an entity object. These are the relevant bits of the entity class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products", indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(columns={"price"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Product
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime;
        $this->updatedAt = $this->createdAt;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I opened `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\PrePersist` and it *is* annotated with `@Annotation`. So the bug seems to be on JMS's side, not Doctrine2.

What can be causing this?

Note: The correct tag in this case would be 'jmsserializer', not 'jmsserializerbundle'. Someone please create it if appropriate and/or remove this note.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up 2 things: Doctrine and JMSSerializer.

You should tell JMSSerializer exactly what you want to be serialized. So try to exclude all and annotate everything you want to have serialized.
Like that:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products", indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(columns={"price"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Product
{
    
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="serializableProperty1", type="guid")
     *
     * @JMS\Expose
     */
    private $serializableProperty1;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime;
        $this->updatedAt = $this->createdAt;
    }

    // ...
}
```